# Why does the same function defined by Set and SetDelayed look different?

Tags: functions, evaluation

I start with the following input:

```
f[n_] = Sum[(1+x)^j, {j,1,n}];
g[n_] := Sum[(1+x)^j, {j,1,n}]
```

When I try to evaluate the code above I get:

```
f[2]
```

$$
\dfrac{(1+x)(-1+(1+x)^2)}{x}
$$

```
g[2]
```

$$
1+x+(1+x)^2
$$

Why is this the case?

Comment: This is because in the definition with `Set` the expression is evaluated first. Mathematica can symbolically manipulate `Sum`s even when `n` does not have a value. To see this, you can evaluate the expression `Sum[(1 + x)^j, {j, 1, n}]` when `n` does not have a value, and see that it evaluates to the same thing as you can see in `f//Definition`.

Comment: Also compare `f[2]//Expand` and `g[2]//Expand`. Lastly I think the question looks quite alright :).

Comment: Yeap, I got it. Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).